# Comparing just content of xml responses using groovy script

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, groovy

I have 2 xml responses and want to compare only the main content

Example as follows:

XML1:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <soapenv:Header>
          <ebl:RequesterCredentials soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns="urn:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:ebl="urn:apis:eBLBaseComponents">         
          </ebl:RequesterCredentials>
       </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <UserResponse xmlns="urn:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
          <Name>Sam</Name>
          <ID>98765</ID>
          <City>SFO</City>
          </UserResponse>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

XML2:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

       <soap:Body>
        <UserResponse>
          <Name>Sam</Name>
          <ID>98764</ID>
          <City>SFO</City>
          </UserResponse>
     </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

I would like to compare only the content inside UserResponse and like to ignore all other stuff.  I just given example above where i mentioned only about 3 elements in response. I have use cases where i will see 100s of elements in response and want to compare both the response for all those 100 elements.Please suggest how to proceed with Groovy script for this.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You couldn't find any tutorials with Google?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with Groovy 2.4.5:

```
def xml1 = """
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <soapenv:Header>
          <ebl:RequesterCredentials soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns="urn:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:ebl="urn:apis:eBLBaseComponents">         
          </ebl:RequesterCredentials>
       </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <UserResponse xmlns="urn:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
          <Name>Sam</Name>
          <ID>98765</ID>
          <City>SFO</City>
          </UserResponse>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
"""

def xml2 = """
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

       <soap:Body>
        <UserResponse>
          <Name>Sam</Name>
          <ID>98764</ID>
          <City>SFO</City>
          </UserResponse>
     </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
"""

def xs1 = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml1)
def xs2 = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml2)

def nameCheck = (xs1.Body.UserResponse.Name.text() == xs2.Body.UserResponse.Name.text())
def idCheck = (xs1.Body.UserResponse.ID.text() == xs2.Body.UserResponse.ID.text())
def cityCheck = (xs1.Body.UserResponse.City.text() == xs2.Body.UserResponse.City.text())

println "nameCheck: ${nameCheck} idCheck: ${idCheck} cityCheck: ${cityCheck}"
```

Comment: Thanks for checking this. But the main prob for me is when i have bulk number of output fields say like i have 100 fields in the response. Its very difficult to proceed with this approach. There should be some easy way but not am not getting that.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention anything about that. Please update your question to be accurate. People are wasting time writing answers if they don't know what you are asking.